# Python - I tried scraping items with scrapy however, the image links are not scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to python and web scraping and I tried scraping contents from this website but I am unable to get the images when I run the crawler.

Here's the spider.py:

```
class TestSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'testscraper'
page_number = 2
start_urls = ['https://jamaicaclassifiedonline.com/auto/cars/']

def parse(self, response):
    items = scrapeItem()

    product_title = response.css('.jco-card-title::text').extract()
    product_imagelink = response.css('.b-loaded::attr(src)').getall()

    items['product_title'] = product_title
    items['product_imagelink'] = product_imagelink

    yield items
```

He's the code for items.py:

```
class scrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
product_title = scrapy.Field()
product_imagelink = scrapy.Field()

pass
```

Comment: It gives the title but not the image link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.css('.card-image img::attr(src)').getall() # images.
response.css('.card-image img::attr(data-src)').getall() # lazy-loaded images.
```